# How to change all users Ad Email contact using powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I need a script that will change all of my ad users email contact field information. The format will be the "SAMAccountName + @domain.com". I am a powershell noob and need a little help on the syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you are using Exchange, E-mail Address Policies are the way to go for this

Comment: Do you have available the [ActiveDirectory Powershell modules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx)? Is your domain 2008R2, or do you have [Active Directory Management Gateway Service](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2852) installed?

Comment: I do not have active directory powershell modules installed yet and yes my domain is 2008 r2.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I would do:

[Install the Active Directory Powershell Module](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rkramesh/archive/2012/01/17/how-to-add-active-directory-module-in-powershell-in-windows-7.aspx)

Script it like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter *
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $email = $user.samaccountname + '@domain.com'
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname -EmailAddress $email
}
```

Comment: $users | Foreach-Object { $email = $_.samaccountname ... would be the better choice here. Especially when processing a large amount of data. Read here for more information: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/

Comment: @Tom Unless you do something like `-Properties *`, it's not going to be that much of a difference, but fair point

Comment: I know - I'm a bit nitpicking. But I think everyone should know the difference between the two methods.